# Directory Application Security

Tags: php, security, authentication, login-control

So, I have two types of users who may login or register: merchants or buyers.

When I login as a buyer, using: `action="check_buyer.php"`, it redirects me to `login/buyer/` on my website. But, right now, once logged in I can change the url from `login/buyer` to `login/merchant` and it works. How do I prevent this? As you can see I'm using sessions...

How do I implement below in PHP a check for `$_POST['userPermission'];` that would be stored as INT(1) in the database and called upon in my sessions ??

```
<?php
session_start(); #recall session from index.php where user logged include()

require_once('../inc/db/dbc.php');
$connect = mysql_connect($h, $u, $p) or die ("Can't Connect to Database.");
mysql_select_db($db);

$LoginUserName = $_POST['userName'];
$LoginPassword = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['userPass']);
//connect to the database here
$LoginUserName = mysql_real_escape_string($LoginUserName);
$query = "SELECT uID, uUPass, dynamSalt
        FROM User
        WHERE uUName = '$LoginUserName';";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if(mysql_num_rows($result) < 1) //no such USER exists
{
    echo "Invalid Username and/or Password";
}
$ifUserExists = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);

$dynamSalt = $ifUserExists['dynamSalt'];  #get value of dynamSalt in query above
$SaltyPass = hash('sha512',$dynamSalt.$LoginPassword); #recreate originally created dynamic, unique pass

if($SaltyPass != $ifUserExists['uUPass']) # incorrect PASS
{
    echo "Invalid Username and/or Password";
}

else {
validateUser();
}
// If User *has not* logged in yet, keep on /login
if(!isLoggedIn())
{
    header('Location: index.php');
    die();
}

function validateUser()
{
    session_regenerate_id ();
    $_SESSION['valid'] = 1;
    $_SESSION['uID'] = $userid;
}

function isLoggedIn()
{
    if(isset($_SESSION['valid']) && $_SESSION['valid'])
        header( 'Location: buyer/' ); # return true if sessions are made and login creds are valid
    echo "Invalid Username and/or Password";  
    return false;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should save the type of user when login into the session and check in the page headers if the type is correct or die the page/redirect/show a message...

Example:

1.- Retrive $type from the table for example from a "userType" field

```
$query = "SELECT uID, uUPass, dynamSalt,userType FROM User WHERE uUName = '$LoginUserName';";
```

2.- Add to the session when login the type value

```
function validateUser() {
    session_regenerate_id ();
    $_SESSION['valid'] = 1;
    $_SESSION['uID'] = $userid;
    $_SESSION['type'] = $userType; // 1 for buyer - 2 for merchant
}
```

3.- On each page limited to a user use a code on head to get if the user is valid

Example for page only for buyer:

```
session_start();
if($_SESSION['type']!=1){ die("You are not a buyer. Access denied"}

// The rest of your page here
```

Example for page only for merchant:

```
session_start();
if($_SESSION['type']!=2){ die("You are not a merchant. Access denied"}

// The rest of your page here
```

Comment: I think userType is tinyint (0 or 1) is the best option

Comment: Thanks to you both! Hit the nail on head!